# Did our comments get bigger?

Tags: bug, design, comments

A while back, we noticed that our comments seemed to get a little bigger. I went and poked around a few other sites and it seems like Meta.SE, Parenting, Academia, and Programmers all have 15px in the body text and 13px for comments, but EL&U has 15px in the body and 14px for comments.

Can the comments go (or go back) to 13px or however that is so it is consistent with other sites?

Comment: I just checked. Meta ELU has 15/13 and Main ELU has 15/14.

Comment: Wonder what prompted the change.

Comment: Looks okay to me. Why make it smaller and difficult to read?

Comment: I rather preferred the 13px, as it helped better to distinguish at a glance between posts and comments.